# Flink SQL ROW_NUMBER aggregation error due to OVER windows' ordering in stream mode must be defined on a time attribute

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

`SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, DEPT_NAME, LOGGED_IN_AT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY LOGGED_IN_AT ASC ) AS ROWNUM FROM inputTable`

Facing error: OVER windows' ordering in stream mode must be defined on a time attribute.

TRIED TUMBLE WINDOW AS

`SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, DEPT_NAME, LOGGED_IN_AT, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY LOGGED_IN_AT ASC ) AS ROWNUM FROM TUMBLE (inputTable, DESCRIPTOR (LOGGED_IN_AT), INTERVAL '24' HOUR)`

It gives parse error, is there any way to aggregate this over time window

Comment: If the ```OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY LOGGED_IN_AT ASC ) AS ROWNUM``` is removed then it works fine

Answer (score 2):

This error

> OVER windows' ordering in stream mode must be defined on a time attribute.

is complaining that you don't have watermarking defined on the `LOGGED_IN_AT` column. The role is watermarking is to inform Flink about the extent to which the rows of your table can be out-of-order. When operating in streaming mode, Flink needs this information in order to be able to sort the table. (By the way, tumble windows also require time attributes.)

This explained in more detail [in the documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/concepts/time_attributes/#introduction-to-time-attributes).